# Laplace Transform of Term in Nonlinear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Is it possible to find the Laplace transform of $y'\text{e}^\text{y}$? I'm trying to find a way to estimate the solution of the following ODE using analytical techniques:

\begin{align*}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; y''- y'\text{e}^\text{ay} = 32, \;\;\;\;\;\; \text{where $a$ is a constant} \end{align*}

I'm hoping to find a series representation of y(t) so that I can estimate y values for several t values. I'm already using Runge-Kutta for numerical estimates. I've experimented with using a combination of assuming  \begin{align*}y(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}t^n \end{align*}  and laplace transform, but I keep hitting a dead end. Does anyone have any techniques to deal with this ODE? Maybe start by rewriting as a system of differential equations and go from there?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the Laplace transform be of any help for solving this kind of non-linear ODE.

Hint : The first integration is easy.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{e^{ay}}{a}=32x+c$$
The second integration is more difficult (it involves the erfi function).